# Display certain line of a file and then translate to uppercase in linux

Tags: linux, command, command-line-interface

Trying to display the 2nd line of a file and then translating it to uppercase.

tried `head 2 file | tr [a-z] [A-Z]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n '2{p;q;}' file.txt | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

or

```
awk 'NR==2{print toupper($0);exit}' file.txt
```

or

```
head -n2 file.txt | tail -n1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

The form `[:lower:] [:upper:]` is the recommended way (`POSIX` classes)

Comment: Is it possible to display the line with head?

Comment: Ah I see so you have to pipe it to tail, that's no good. Sed works I guess. Thank you.

Comment: This did not work. The question on my assignment is: `Your current directory is assign2. Display the 2nd line of the file cars2, translated
to uppercase`. cars2 is in assign2/stenton/gen_ed/cars2. No idea how to do this D:

Comment: I gave you 3 workings commands, you just need to adapt it a bit & remember your courses when your professor was explaining you to use paths. Try searching a bit, I will not do all your homeworks =)

Comment: It's not okay now, still stumped. Tried every variation. Tried `tr [a-z] [A-Z]` (like in course examples for translate). Tried the `'[:lower:]'` and `[:lower:]` with upper as well. Did `head -2 file | tail -1 | tr <trmethods>` as well switching the head and tail. I tested all this on my server but it still does not work for the homework.

Comment: Anyway, praise awk since most recent awks have toupper:  awk 'NR==2 {print toupper($0)}'

Comment: Thanks MeaCulpa, added in my post.

Comment: Here is the solution: `head -2 stenton/gen_ed/cars2 | tail -1 | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`. The `tr` arguments needed to be in single quotes.

Comment: As already said, `'[a-z]' '[A-Z]'` should written `'[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` See `man tr`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
head -2 file | tail -1 | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]"
```